# how to use mysqli_real_escape_string for $_GET['page']

Tags: php, pagination

I am using a pagination for a guestbook and i want to protect the 'page' with real escape string
This is what i have now:

```
$page = (int)(!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
```

If tried this but the paginations seems not to work anymmore:

```
$page = (int)(!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET["page"]));
```

What should i do to make this work?

Comment: Well if you [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) it says when calling the function procedurally the arguments are: `mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`. So you need to pass the mysqli connection as the first argument.

Comment: If `$_GET['page']` is a number, you technically don't need to escape it. If you convert it to int (by doing `(int)$_GET['page']`) then there is no risk of malicious injection; it'll always be converted to a number.

Comment: Besides, if you are using MySQLi to begin with, you really should be using prepared statements, not old-school escaping.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Change `mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET["page"]));` to `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["page"]));` that's why it's not working, to "answer" the question.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I also notice that it is not really necessary to escape because it is a number.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any string escaping here, because you've forced the variable to be an integer instead. Even if you turn the integer back into a string, it will only contain digits, so there is no way for anyone to inject SQL into your query.